# Hide DIVS and Table/Rows/ based on key word it contains

Tags: jquery

I have a parent `DIV` and this `DIV` contains multiple child `DIV`S and `Table`s within.

I would like to hide all `DVI`S and `Table`s containing specific keyword with in the parent `DIV`.

How can I perform a search and hide `DIV`S and `Table`s containing specific keyword?

```
function searchFunction() {
    var searchTerm = "shipping";
    $(".ships").each(function(){
        $(this).(":contains('"+searchTerm+"')").hide(); 
    });
```

Comment: I tried this: 

function searchFunction() {
          var searchTerm = "shipping";
          $(".ships").each(function(){
              $(this).(":contains('"+searchTerm+"')").hide(); 
           });

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`:contains('key')`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

```
$("div:contains('" + keyword + "')")
```

Update for your code above:

```
$(".ships:contains('" + searchTerm + "')").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks @megawac. It has tables/rows as well.